# how to fix this Error in the Library (build gradle)?

Tags: android-studio

hier the error message,

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Strg+F1) 
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).  Issue id: GradleCompatible

Answer (score 2):

Change your gradle dependency

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```