# Version Mismatch in Google Play Advert Library

Tags: android-studio

I my dependencies I have the latest libraries:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

The bottom one (`com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0`) is underlined in red and complains

All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification.

I am using the 28 version I want for the compatibility I want (Kitkat) and the adverts one is the latest one.

Why am I getting this error?

**NOTE: I have tried the solutions already on this forum for this error. (Ie changing 17.1.2 to 28.0.0 does not work.)**

Comment: its look duplicate try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648229/how-to-fix-this-error-in-the-library-build-gradle

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As explained changing the 17.1.2 in the adverts to 28.0.0 does not work. Because that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adverts uses an old version, so need to suppress the error warning with the following before the `appcompat` line:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your error message showing `"com.android.support:<module>:<version>"` then you have to replace that module version with 28.0.0 `"com.android.support:<module>:28.0.0"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As explained changing the 17.1.2 in the adverts to 28.0.0 does not work. Because that does not exist.

Comment: My statements only for the reference, that you can apply for any library